# Can't use excel macro keyboard shortcuts

Tags: vba, excel

I'm editing an excel file and although I've enabled macros, every time I try to use a shortcut to use the macro, I get the pop up alert: `"Because of your security settings, macros have been disabled. To run macros, you need to reopen this workbook, and then choose to enable macros"`
I don't get a prompt when I reopen the workbook. I've opened the developer tab, gone to macro security, and enabled all macros. I can run macros from the macro tab by clicking in the macro code and hitting f5. I just can't use the keyboard shortcuts.
I'm using excel 2013 in windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate the following

a)
[image]

b)
[image]

Then play with their activation in order to check the best security options left

***Edit:***

 Unblock the file from the properties window

[image]

Comment: Both of them? That should let excel do anything since security is gone in all senses, does the macro plays with VBA environment? If so, the thick box is needed to trust access...

Comment: Yes, both of them.
I agree, it should let excel do anything.

Comment: Very weird indeed, I'm clueless,check my updated response; if that doesn't work, have you tried to record one from your pc and see if the shortcuts work from books that you do in your pc and your external are the ones problematic?